# Attach to Android process from Qt Creator

Tags: android, c++, qt, remote-debugging

I use Qt Creator to develop an Android dynamic library, i.e. a .so file. This .so file is then used by an Android application, but that is developed in Eclipse.

I need to debug my native code, but since it's a library, I can't start the application from Qt Creator, I **must attach to the already running process**.

Now, if it were a desktop application, I'd use `Debug->Start Debugging->Attach to Running Application`, but how do I attach to an Android process, which would be running on the emulator or on a connected phone, which is more like remote-debugging?

I think that I should use `Debug->Start Debugging->Attach to Running Debug Server`:

[image]

However, I'm not sure what the exact steps are - how do I start a debug server for ADB, and which port do I connect to?

Comment: Are you able to copy the source of the eclipse project into Qt Creator's project?

Answer (score 3):

So it looks like there may be another way to set up a debugger that can connect properly.

http://lists.qt-project.org/pipermail/qt-creator/2012-June/001017.html

> Set a toolchain with this version of gdb, and set your project to use it.
>   In Tools -> Options -> Debugger -> GDB insert your commands in "Additional
>   Startup Commands"

...

> I use Debug -> Start Debugging -> Attach to Remote. All the fields are
>   there (solib-absolute-prefix is an alias for sysroot, and "location of
>   debugging information" is solib-search-path), and the last few
>   "configurations" are stored, so you can call them back easily. I have
>   to start gdbserver on the target manually, set a shortcut to open the
>   'attach to remote' dialog, and it is been working great for me so for.

It's old (June 2012), but it goes into better detail about how the `gdbserver` is started and the setup for a debugger and attaching to a process in Qt.  It also mentions some of the relevant environment variables:

> ```
> set solib-absolute-prefix $ANDROID_SRC/out/target/product/MYPRODUCT/symbols/
> set solib-search-path $ANDROID_SRC/out/target/product/MYPRODUCT/symbols/system/lib/
> ```

Hope that helps.

Comment: How do I start gdbserver? Do I log into `adb shell`? What do I type in there adb?

Comment: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/wiki/Android-debugging-with-remote-GDB

Answer (score 0):

Attaching to a `adb logcat` is independent of Qt and what Android source you are using.  Make sure `adb.exe` can be found on your path such as: `C:\Android\SDK\platform-tools`, and you have the adb drivers for the device you are debugging with.  Try this one if you are struggling: http://www.koushikdutta.com/post/universal-adb-driver

### Command Line ADB commands

This should print out any connected devices that can be found:

```
adb devices
```

This clears the current logcat logs:

```
adb logcat -c
```

This starts a connection to logcat:

```
adb logcat
```

Usually you don't have to worry about which port to connect to, because it is automatically found by adb.

Attaching to logcat over wifi is also do-able.

```
adb tcpip
adb connect 192.168.XX.XX:5555
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure how that addresses my question. I wasn't asking about logcat, I already can read logcat's output from Eclipse. I need to debug native code in a shared library. By debugging I mean setting breakpoints, tracing/stepping the code line by line.

Comment: I know in eclipse you can setup a sources folder for when you step into a library's function...  Then it should show all the possible information.  I'm sorry I missed the intent of your question the first time.

Comment: I develop the dynamic library in Qt Creator, not in Eclipse. I can't develop it in Eclipse, I need to compile it in Qt Creator and copy the binary to Eclipse. The reason it is uses the Qt libraries, so I need to use Qt's toolchain. So that other suggestion is not an option, either. What I need is to attach to the process from Qt Creator - which what my question is.