# Qt Android : how can I use logcat in Qt?

Tags: android, qt, qtandroidextras

Is there a way to see `logcat` in Qt, so I can debug easier? Specially, that my code uses android service, which runs on a separate process and I can't see any QDebug or QWarning or Log.

Comment: Have you looked into the command line tool [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat.html) of logcat?

Comment: Yes i just did, and also a summary here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6854127/filter-logcat-to-get-only-the-messages-from-my-application-in-android
It solved my problem

Comment: So your problem is solved with your provided link?

Comment: Yes, and this too is very useful
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32279371/8086424