# Qt android : Is there a way to see QDebug output from android service?

Tags: android, qt, qtandroidextras

I need to see the qDebug or qWarning output from C++ that is generated when an android service runs in Qt, in order to debug faster and easier.

But, since the android service in Qt runs on a separate process, I cannot see qDebug that is generated from the C++ service code. For ex. by using: `qWarning("Hello");` as I normally do in the app C++ code.

Is there a way?

N.B
Using logcat, I was able to see the messages from the java class that starts the service only. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44387029/qt-android-how-can-i-use-logcat-in-qt?noredirect=1#comment75777417_44387029) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6854182/8086424).

But now i want to display qDebug messages from the C++ code of the service.

Comment: I think you should mention your previous post, indicate the difference and mention what you have tried so far, i.e. how do you display your output?

Comment: I don't know if that is possible, but if there is no way I can suggest you write a simple network logger yourself and send the debug messages via socket or HTTP to some log service (or write your own socket server). It may sound complicated but it's only a few lines of code in Qt and if you only use it for debugging it's easy to implement.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/45460081/2404492